# Duplicating relations vs executing more queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have the following architecture.

[image]

You will find a duplication in `HAS` relationship. The main one is between `Badge` and `Skill` as I want to be able to aggregate/count same `Skill` from different `Badge` of the same `User`.

So, the duplicate relationship is between `User` and `Skill`. That is because, for instance, if an `Organization` wants to know all the skills of single or multiple recipients I would follow the following path:

```
 Org -OWNS-> Badges -IS_AWARDED_To-> User -HAS-> Skill
//Skill nodes for a specific or multiple user represent each skill contained in every Badge the user was awarded.
```

However, if I do not add the duplicated relationship `HAS` between `User` and `Skill`, I will follow the following path instead:

```
Org -OWNS-> Badges -IS_AWARDED_TO-> User -IS_AWARDED-> Badges -HAS-> Skill
//Now I have all skills for a specific or multiple User for every badge awarded
```

The difference between the two paths is obvious. The first one will result in less queries but the duplication of the relationship is a concern. The second one will remove the duplication problem (is it a problem?) but has more queries. I am still a newbie to neo4j and feel free to tell me that both of my approaches seem convoluted and there is a more optimized way to reach what I am trying to do.

Comment: when you say `less` or `more` query, you speak about the complexity of the query and so the execution time, right ?

Comment: Yes, I am speaking in general about the logical choice. Achieving the result with less queries is the better alternative from my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two models are valid, and you can use both of them.

But like you said, on the first one you duplicate some data. Generally we do that when we have some performance issues. Is it your case for now ?

As a starting point, **I recommend you to start with the model 2** (ie. without duplication), and if you have some issues with this model, you can easely change it to the model 1 (the flexibility of Neo4j is really great for graph refactoring !).

In IT, nothing is free : if you duplicate some data to have better performances in reads, you will have an impact on writes.

When you write a `(badge)-[:HAS]->(skill)` relationship, you also need to create a `(user)-[:HAS]->(skill)` rel (same for update or delete).

So you need to keep the consistency of this data when you update the graph. In fact it's like you are creating a SQL stored view.